# What is a reasonable value for heartbeat in RabbitMQ?

Tags: rabbitmq

RabbitMQ allows you to "heartbeat" a connection, i.e. from time to time the client and the server check (using empty messages) that the other party is still there and available. So far, so good.

Unfortunately, I was not able to find a place in the documentation where a suggestion is made what a reasonable value for this is. I know that you need to specify the heartbeat in seconds, but what is a real-world best practice value?

Obviously, it should not be too often (traffic), but also not too rare (proxies, …). Any suggestions?

Is 15 seconds fine? 30? 60? …?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The RabbitMQ documentation now provides a recommended heartbeat timeout value between 5 and 20 seconds:

> Setting heartbeat timeout value too low can lead to false positives (peer being considered unavailable while it really isn't the case) due to transient network congestion, short-lived server flow control, and so on. This should be taken into consideration when picking a timeout value.
>
> Several years worth of feedback from the users and client library maintainers suggest that values lower than 5 seconds are fairly likely to cause false positives, and values of 1 second or lower are very likely to do so. Values within the 5 to 20 seconds range are optimal for most environments.

Source: https://www.rabbitmq.com/heartbeats.html#false-positives

In addition, as of RabbitMQ 3.5.5 the default heartbeat timeout value is 60 seconds (https://www.rabbitmq.com/heartbeats.html#heartbeats-timeout)

Answer (score 12):

**This answer if for RabbitMQ < 3.5.5, for newer versions see the answer from @bmaupin.**

It depends on your application needs. Out of the box it is 10 min for RabbitMQ. If you fail to ack heartbeat twice (20min of inactivity), connection will be closed immediately without sending any connection.close method or any error from the broker side.

The case to use heartbeat is firewalls that closes inactive for a long time connection or some other network settings that doesn't allow you to have waiting connections.

In fact, hearbeat is not a must, from [RabbitMQ config doc](https://www.rabbitmq.com/configure.html#config-items)

> **heartbeat**
>
> Value representing the heartbeat delay, in seconds, that the server sends in the connection.tune frame. If set to 0, heartbeats are disabled. Clients might not follow the server suggestion, see the AMQP reference for more details. Disabling heartbeats might improve performance in situations with a great number of connections, but might lead to connections dropping in the presence of network devices that close inactive connections.
> Default: 580

Note, that having hearbeat interval too short may result in significant network overhead. Keep in mind, that hearbeat frames are sent when there are no other activity on the connection for a hearbeat time interval.

Comment: Is it okay to set the heartbeat to be 1 hour? How do I ack heartbeat from client side?

Comment: IIRC, the RMQ mentions something like "most clients treat regular traffic as heartbeats, though some don't"